# Get folder's content in an usable variables

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to get all files names from a directory in variables ?
Consider this environment :

```
Dir/File.json
Dir/File7.json
Dir/File58.exe
```

Is it possible so that i can get `File`, and `File7` (only the file with `.json` extension) in one or two variables that i'd use later in my code ?

I test dir > test.txt but : It show everything including folder or files with an other extension, and i don't know if i can then use this .txt file to get back the names individualy.

Using `PowerShell`

Comment: Yes it is possible but if you're asking this this way I'd recommend for you to start learning the very basics of Powershell. It is far beyond the scope of SO to teach you how to code in Powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$FileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Dir' -Name *.json
```

This will return all json files in the folder C:\Dir

Comment: Great! I'm proud of you.

Comment: Thanks you, but then can i use these names returned ? If so, How ?

Comment: `$FileNames = Get-ChildItem -Name *.json
foreach ($element in $FileNames) {
    Write-Output "L'element est $element"
}`

Seems working. Thanks

Comment: There is still something. The command return `filename.json` but what if i just want filename?

Comment: `foreach ($element in $FileNames) {
    $element = $element -replace(".json","")
    Write-Output "L'element est $element"
}`

This work. Don't know if there is a better way.
Thanks anyway